# Como descobrir todos os objeto em um JoyStick?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, directx

Estou compilando um projeto para Win32 utilizando a biblioteca DirectInput do DirectX para gerenciar Joysticks.

Tentei com sucesso identificar se algum Joystick está conectado através da enumeração:

```
uses
    Classes,      Winapi.DirectInput,   FMX.Platform.Win,
    SysUtils,     WinAPI.Windows,       FMX.Dialogs,
    StartUpCopy,                        FMX.Forms,
    Generics.Collections;

var
    DI          : IDirectInput;
    KeyBoard    : IDirectInputDevice;
    JoySticks   : TList<IDirectInputDevice>;
    I           : Integer;

begin
    JoySticks := TList<IDirectInputDevice>.Create();
    DirectInput8Create(HInstance, DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8W, DI, nil);
    DI.EnumDevices(
        DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL, 
        @function(var lpddi: TDIDeviceInstanceW; pvRef: Pointer) : BOOL
        var
            JS : IDirectInputDevice;
        begin
            if not FAILED(DI.CreateDevice(lpddi.guidInstance, JS, nil)) then
            begin
                JoySticks.Add(JS);
                Result := DIENUM_STOP;
            end
            else
                Result := DIENUM_CONTINUE;
        end, nil, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY);
    if (JoySticks.Count < 1) then
    begin
        ShowMessage('Joystick não encontrado.');
        Halt;
    end;  
    // ...
```

Porém para de fato identificar os objeto dos Joysticks tenho um erro bem esquisito no seguinte trecho:

```
    for I := 0 to JoySticks.Count do
    begin
        JoySticks[I].SetDataFormat(c_dfDIJoystick2);
        JoySticks[I].SetCooperativeLevel(ApplicationHWND, DISCL_FOREGROUND or DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
        JoySticks[I].EnumObjects(
            @function(var lpddoi: TDIDeviceObjectInstanceW; pvRef : Pointer) : BOOL
            var
                PropRange : DIPROPRANGE;
            begin
                PropRange.diph.dwSize       := SizeOf(DIPROPRANGE);
                PropRange.diph.dwHeaderSize := SizeOf(DIPROPHEADER);
                PropRange.diph.dwHow        := DIPH_BYID;
                PropRange.diph.dwObj        := lpddoi.dwType;
                PropRange.lMin              := -1000;
                PropRange.lMax              := 1000;
                Result                      := DIENUM_CONTINUE;
                if FAILED(JoySticks[I].SetProperty(DIPROP_RANGE, PropRange.diph)) then
                    Result := DIENUM_STOP;

                { De acordo com o Debugger, o erro (Access Violation) 
                acontece após o fim das instruções no Callback, o que 
                é estranho uma vez que o código do callback em sí não 
                causa erro algum. }

            end, nil, DIDFT_ALL);
        if(JoySticks[I].Acquire <> DI_OK) then
            ShowMessage('Acq Faild');
    end;
end;
```

Encontrei pouca documentação em Delphi sobre o assunto, na verdade o código em sí é uma "tradução" de [um exemplo em C#](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jparise/directx/joystick/) que encontrei.

O que falta neste processo? O que estou deixando passar? Alguém já implementou este tipo de rotina em Delphi por aqui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, o erro está acontecendo por causa do tipo de procedimento utilizado em `IDirectInputDeviceW.EnumObjects`. O método declarado no cabeçalho é o seguinte:

```
function EnumObjects(lpCallback: TDIEnumDeviceObjectsCallbackW; pvRef: Pointer; dwFlags: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
```

O tipo `TDIEnumDeviceObjectsCallbackW`, por sua vez refere-se ao seguinte tipo de procedimento:

```
TDIEnumDeviceObjectsCallbackW = function (var lpddoi: TDIDeviceObjectInstanceW; pvRef : Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Ou seja, uma função regular (*regular procedure*), com a convenção de chamada `StdCall`.

No entanto a função que está sendo passada é do tipo anônima (*reference of function*) e sem uma convenção de chamada explícita caindo na convenção padrão: `Register`.

Esta incompatibilidade gera a Violação de Acesso ao escapar da função executada. Aqui um trecho de código que resolveria o problema:

```
function EnumObjectCallback(var lpdoi : TDIDeviceObjectInstanceW; pvRef : Pointer) : BOOL; StdCall;
begin
    // lpdoi --> conterá o objeto a ser registrado em cada iteração.  
    Result := DIENUM_CONTINUE;
end;

function EnumDeviceCallback(var lpddi: TDIDeviceInstanceW; pvRef: Pointer): BOOL; StdCall;
var
    D : IDirectInputDevice8W;
begin
    if FAILED(DInput.CreateDevice(lpddi.guidInstance, D, nil)) then
        Result := DIENUM_CONTINUE
    else
    begin
        Result := DIENUM_CONTINUE;
        case lpddi.dwDevType and $1F of
            DI8DEVTYPE_MOUSE: D.SetDataFormat(c_dfDIMouse);
            DI8DEVTYPE_KEYBOARD: D.SetDataFormat(c_dfDIKeyboard);
            DI8DEVTYPE_JOYSTICK: D.SetDataFormat(c_dfDIJoystick);
        end;

        D.SetCooperativeLevel(HWND, DISCL_BACKGROUND or DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
        D.EnumObjects(@EnumObjectCallback, nil, DIDFT_ALL);
    end;
```

Para mais referências:

- [Documentação da Microsoft sobre Direct Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842(v=vs.85).aspx);
- [Documentação da Embarcadero sobre Procedimentos e Funções](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedures_and_Functions).